# Android Dynamic multiple spinners creation

Tags: android, dynamic, android-spinner

I have gone through all answers regarding "Creating multiple spinners dynamically", but the multiple spinners that are created are over riding the previously generated spinners. We tried using LayoutParams and params.setMargins,but the view cannot be specified for each spinner generation.

My requirement is to generate "n" spinners, where n is specified as per requirement.
The code that worked partially where each spinner generation overrode each other is below:

```
public class newstatusinfo extends AppCompatActivity {

List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String>a;

Spinner spin;

int a1=5,b1=5,c1=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.witnesslay);

    spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner21);

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new       

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

       values.add(String.valueOf(a1));
       values.add(String.valueOf(b1));
       params.setMargins(0,a1,0,b1);
       System.out.println("a1:"+a1);
       System.out.println("b1:"+b1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android 
       .R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, values);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;     
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
       spin.setLayoutParams(params);

        System.out.println("i:"+i);
       a1=a1+5;
       b1=b1+5;
    }

}}
```

The screenshot is below:

[image]

What we need is multiple spinners like in the above image vertically one by one,each with a certain set of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that if this is what you want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsp6l.png)

You just said that

> Creating multiple spinners dynamically

Does it mean generate Views dynamically by java code? If so, please read my code.I think there is no association relations between using MARGIN and showing Spinner correctly.

```
public class newstatusinfo extends AppCompatActivity {


    int a1 = 0, b1 = 5, c1 = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
        rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
            rootView.addView(spin);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) spin.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            spin.setLayoutParams(params);

            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            values.add(String.valueOf(a1));
            values.add(String.valueOf(b1));
            values.add(String.valueOf(c1));
            System.out.println("a1:" + a1);
            System.out.println("b1:" + b1);
            System.out.println("c1:" + c1);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android
                    .R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, values);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spin.setAdapter(adapter);
            spin.setLayoutParams(params);

            System.out.println("i:" + i);
            a1 = a1 + 5;
            b1 = b1 + 5;
            c1 = c1 + 5;
        }
        setContentView(rootView);
    }
}
```

Comment: We are setting styles for the generated  spinners by passing a reference Layout to ArrayAdapter. It works fine but the default spinner arrow button does not get overrided. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: We are able to fetch and print the values of all spinners but not able to store them.The value of last spinner is getting stored,for the number of times the spinner is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, English is not my native language. There may be several grammatical mistakes and misunderstanding. I will try my best to understand your question and answer them. :-D Here we go:
In my understanding, you issued two question:

> 1 How to set STYLE for spinners' arrow?
>
> 2 How to store values of all spinners?

First, answer the question about STYLE. I am sorry to say that I did not find how to set style for arrow perfectly. But I have two suggestions:

**1.1** you can set color for the spinner's arrow. Like that:

```
        int[][] states = new int[6][2];
        states[0] = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed, android.R.attr.state_enabled};
        states[1] = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_focused};
        states[2] = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled};
        states[3] = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused};
        states[4] = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_window_focused};
        states[5] = new int[]{};
        int[] colors = new int[]{0xffffffff, 0xffffff00, 0xff0000ff, 0xffff0000, 0xff0000ff, 0xffff0000};
        ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        spin.setBackgroundTintList(csl);
```

or declare it in Spinner's Layout file as `android:backgroundTint="#00ff00"` for the Spinner.
If you are comfused about the code above. Please Google the word 'ColorStateList', then you will understand it.
[image: arrow color changed]

**1.2** you can place a TextView where the spinner is. Bind the click event of the Spinner to the TextView. Then you can set the Style for TextView as you like.

**2 store the values:**
Talk is cheap, just show you my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private List<List<String>> spinnersValues = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initData();//store the values of all spinners

        LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
        rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
            rootView.addView(spin);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) spin.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            spin.setLayoutParams(params);

            List<String> values = spinnersValues.get(i);//fetch the values of one of the spinners

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, values);
            spin.setAdapter(adapter);
            spin.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
        setContentView(rootView);
    }


    private void initData() {
        List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>();
        fruits.add("apple");
        fruits.add("pear");
        fruits.add("cherry");
        fruits.add("grape");

        List<String> furniture = new ArrayList<String>();
        furniture.add("desk");
        furniture.add("chair");
        furniture.add("bench");

        List<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
        animals.add("dog");
        animals.add("cat");
        animals.add("cow");
        animals.add("rabbit");
        animals.add("horse");
        animals.add("tiger");
        animals.add("lion");

        spinnersValues.add(fruits);
        spinnersValues.add(furniture);
        spinnersValues.add(animals);
    }
}
```